# In CSS, can I distinguish two buttons with same href value based on the content inside them?

Tags: html, css, frontend

`<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">« Back to Inbox</a>`

has the same href value as

`<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">Refresh</a>` in one of my pages.

---

If I set custom CSS for one, the padding and margin values distort when I open another page with the same button. Do you know a way to distinguish both the entities (I'm guessing based on the content inside them?). I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: No, but this can be achieved by adding a unique tag such as `<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink" data-name="inbox">« Back to Inbox</a>` or using a scripting language like `JQuery` or `Javascript`. This cannot be achieved in plain CSS without some sort of modification. If you're interested in any of these solutions, specify which & I'll supply an example as an answer.

Comment: You can use innerText property or order of element in the page

Comment: you can also use first child css property like `<div id='mydiv'><a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">« Back to Inbox</a><a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">Refresh</a>
</div>` Then CSS will be like `.mydiv a:first-child{background-color:yellow}`

Comment: @EGC I'd love to see an easy solution in JS, thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: I added both CSS and JQuery methods in my answer below.. you can pick one :)

Comment: The simplest options is to give each element two classes ([yes elements can have more than one class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)) . Use `searchPageLink` for the common stuff then use the additional classes to provide link specific differences

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text answers the question of using the text inside the element for selectors (short answer: you can't using only CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plain `Javascript` solution as requested.

```js
var aTags = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
var textToFind = "« Back to Inbox";

aTags.forEach(function(element){
  if(element.textContent == textToFind) {
   element.style.color = 'red';
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">« Back to Inbox</a>

<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">Refresh</a> in one of my pages.
```

Here is also the `CSS` with `HTML` modification example as requested:

```css
a[data-name="inbox"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink" data-name="inbox">« Back to Inbox</a>

<a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink" data-name="refresh">Refresh</a> in one of my pages.
```

Ref: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gadq4927/)

Goodluck!

Let me know if you want to see a `JQuery` solution!

Comment: No worries! The CSS/HTML solution has been included too

Comment: Instead of a data attribute, why not just add a second class, E.g `class="searchPageLink refesh"`?

Comment: Also an option, at the same token, why not add a unique ID called `refresh`. Literally, there are so many solutions to this issue if they're willing to modify the HTML!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$($('.mydiv').find("a")[1]).css("background-color", "green") //Play with second link js
```

```css
.mydiv a:first-child{background-color:yellow} /*play with first link css*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mydiv'>
  <a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">« Back to Inbox</a><br/>
  <a href="?&amp;" class="searchPageLink">Refresh</a> 
</div>
```